# Data Ingestion from SAS to Hive

Tags: hive, sas, hdfs

I have a requirement where the tables from SAS in the form of "abc.sas7bdat" file will be provided at a particular location along with libref(see below code:libname xxx '/workspace/abc/xyz'). I need to create a hive table from this dataset. I am using the below code. This code creates the table in Hive but its empty. Upon further research i noticed that the following parameter may be missing in hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
      <name>dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname</name>
      <value>true</value>
</property>
```

I did not find this property in hdfs-site.xml and that explains why the table is empty.

My question is, I need to ingest data from size ranging 1GB to greater than 200GB. How can I speed up the process? I have access only to Unix machine where the files are dropped and not sure what all has been installed.

Current Code:

```
options set=SAS_HADOOP_RESTFUL=1;
options set=SAS_HADOOP_JAR_PATH=<jar path>;
options set=SAS_HADOOP_CONFIG_PATH=<config path>;
options nofmterr;
%let svr = %NRSTR('server.abc.com');
%let stng = %NRSTR('stored as parquet');
 libname aaa hadoop server=&svr hdfs_tempdir='/tmp/sastmp' user = 'username'
password = pxxx schema='schema name' port 10000
DBCREATE_TABLE_OPTS=`&stng`
subprotocol=hive2;
libname xxx '/workspace/abc/xyz';
data aaa.test;
set xxx.abc.test; 
run;
```

Comment: What does your SAS log state? Anything like `sticky bit`?

Comment: No,log file is clear. I found that missing of below property could be the issue for not loading the data.<property>
      <name>dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname</name>
      <value>true</value>
</property>